How can I quickly collapse all code in all .cs files in a project?
Currently, if I want to collapse all the content of all my .cs files in a project, I have to open each file individually and press CTRL + M, A. This process is quite tedious and time-consuming.
Is there a faster way to collapse all the code across all files in a project?
I’d prefer not to write a custom Visual Studio extension since I’ve never created one before and would rather focus on other tasks right now. However, if it’s a relatively simple and straightforward process, I’d be open to giving it a try.
Specific questions:

Is there an existing extension that offers this functionality?
Are there alternative shortcuts or semi-automatic methods to achieve this?
Could it be done via terminal command, perhaps with Open
in Terminal or a similar approach?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Edit: opened a ticket


Is there a faster way to collapse all the code across all files in a project?

I'm afraid not. Looks like there are no built-in keyboard shortcuts or menu command to achieve it up to now after do some searching.
I would suggest you could raise a feature request.
That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

Thanks for your suggestion, I'm about to do that.

If you do submit a ticket on Developer Community, please kindly share the ticket link with us for better tracking.

Sure, here's the link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Collapse-code-in-all-cs-files-in-a-solu/10799448
I've also edited the question description including it there.

Use this shortcut to it:

CTRL+M+O

You can go in Edit/Outlining/Colopse to Definions.
Not in all files, but is just one command and you collpse all your code.

Yeah, exactly: as I wrote in the post, I need to collapse everything (CTRL + M + A) in all scripts, not just the methods in a single script.
Thanks anyway for your response :)
